# Show that $E$ is a vector subspace with $\operatorname{dim} E=m-1$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove this result:
Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set, $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function, and $x_0\in U$  such that $f(x_0)=0$ and $Df(x_0)\neq0$. Let $E$ be the set of all the velocity vectors $\lambda'(0)$ of the paths $\lambda:[-1,1]\to U$ such that $\lambda(0)=x_0$ and $f(\lambda(t))=0$ for every $t\in[-1,1]$. Show that $U$ is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ with $\operatorname{dim} E=m-1$.

It is clear that this set is non empty because the constant path $\lambda(t)=x_0$ satifies every condition, but I have no idea how to continue this argument. I'd apreciate some hints, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are given a path $\lambda$ then the chain rule shows that $Df(x_0) \lambda'(0) = 0$. Hence $\lambda'(0) \in \ker Df(x_0)$.

Now suppose $\lambda \in \ker Df(x_0)$, and consider
$\phi(s,t) = f(x_0+s \lambda + t Df(x_0)^T)$. It is easy to check that
$\phi(0,0) = 0$, ${\partial \phi(0,0) \over \partial s} =0$ and ${\partial \phi(0,0) \over \partial t} = \|Df(x_0)\|^2 >0$,
hence the implicit function theorem gives some locally defined $C^1$ function $\tau$
such that $\phi(s,\tau(s)) = 0$ locally.

Now define $l(s) = x_0+s \lambda + \tau(s) Df(x_0)^T$ and check that $l'(0) = \lambda$.

Hence $E = \ker Df(x_0)$.

Note that $\dim {\cal R} Df(x_0) = 1$ and use the rank nullity theorem to finish.