# Proving there exists a subspace with dimension 1 satisfying a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Came across this question in an exercise sheet

Let $V$ be a vector space of functions 
$V = $ {$f: [-1,1] \Rightarrow $ $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ continuous} 
For  subspace $U$ of $V$ prove or disprove that there exists subspace $W$ with dimension $1$ and $V = U\oplus W$ 
$U$ = {$f \in V$: $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\ dx$ exists and $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)\ dx = 0$} 

I have no idea how to even start this question, any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea. First take a finite-dimensional $V$ and look up how to obtain a subspace $U$ of codimension $1$ and $V=U\oplus W$. Then compare with your example and look for a linear equation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde could you provide a link where it shows how to obtain a subspace $U$ of codimension $1$ and $V = U \oplus W$? I couldn't find anything

Comment: The condition ''$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) dx$ exists' is redundant because $f$ is continuos. Hint: ''what would you add to $U$ to be $V$????''

Comment: Also compare to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752268/show-that-e-is-a-vector-subspace-with-operatornamedim-e-m-1?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=[-1,1]$ and $V=C(X)$. Let $A: X \to \mathbb{C}$ be the linear functional $Af=\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx$. Pick $v_0 \in V$ such that $Av_0=1$. Any $v \in V$ can then be written as $v=u+\alpha v_0, \alpha=Av \in \mathbb{C}$, where $u=v-\alpha v_0 \in \ker A$. This decomposes $V$ into $\ker A$ and the one dimensional space spanned by $v_0$. There is nothing special about $A$ in these terms.